# Material-UI File Upload: while click Button, not opening the file select option, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, file, button, input, material-ui

File upload option not opening in the material-ui Button, not sure how to fix it.

```
InputProps={{
    endAdornment:
        (<InputAdornment position="end" style={{height: '24px'}}>
            <Button size={'medium'}>
                Attach +
                <input
                    onChange={handleFile}
                    type="file"
                    hidden
                />
            </Button>
        </InputAdornment>)
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After readed official document I have added **component="label"** property to Button and issue resolved

```
InputProps={{
        endAdornment:
            (<InputAdornment position="end" style={{height: '24px'}}>
                <Button size={'medium'} component="label"> // added  component="label"
                    Attach +
                    <input
                        onChange={handleFile}
                        type="file"
                        hidden
                    />
                </Button>
            </InputAdornment>)
    }}
```